# Filesize excessive Java

Tags: java, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have a problem with these two classes, when the size of the file to send \ receive exceeds 1GB.The class Decripter waits for something, before closing the stream to the output file, which appears to have been received in full (by controlling the size). Cripter class instead finishes successfully without any errors. Since the size of the complete file too big, I can not use debugging. I can not understand what the problem since (I think) to have properly closed all streams. This is the class for sending:

```
 public class Cripter {


     ObjectOutputStream out;

     FileInputStream fis2;

     BufferedInputStream bis;

     File iFile;

     public Cripter(File tmpFile, ObjectOutputStream tmpOut) {
         //Definizione degli stream
         in = tmpIn;
         out = tmpOut;
         iFile = tmpFile;
         splitFile();
     }

     private void splitFile() {
         FileInputStream fis;

         long fileSize = iFile.length();
         int read = 0;
         long readLength = 10000000;
         Client.writeLabelSender("Criptaggio del file " + iFile.getName() + " in corso...");
         byte[] byteChunk;
         try {
             //Invio il nome completo del file
             out.writeObject(iFile.getName());
             //Invio della dimensione completa
             out.writeObject(fileSize);
             fis = new FileInputStream(iFile);
             while (fileSize > 0) {
                 if (fileSize <= readLength) {
                     readLength = fileSize;
                 }
                 byteChunk = new byte[(int) readLength];
                 read = fis.read(byteChunk, 0, (int) readLength);
                 fileSize -= read;
                 //Lunghezza
                 out.writeObject(read);
                 //Invio
                 out.write(byteChunk, 0, byteChunk.length);
                 out.flush();
                 byteChunk = null;
             }
             fis.close();
             fis = null;
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
```

This is the class for receiving:

```
public class Decripter {
    /**
     * byte letti
     */
    int bytesRead = 0;
    /**
     * Directory in cui salvare il file completo
     */
    private static String directory;
    /**
     * Nome del file completo
     */
    private static String fileName;
    /**
     * Stream di input
     */
    public ObjectInputStream in ;

    /**
     * Dimensione del file completo
     */
    long dimensione;
    /**
     * File utilizzato per comporre il file finale
     */
    File oFile;

    //Stream
    FileOutputStream fos;
    FileInputStream fis;
    FileOutputStream fosTx;

    /**
     * Costruttore che inizializza il nome e la directory del file ed effettua il riassemblamento
     * @param name nome del file completo
     * @param dir Parte del percorso successiva a FileDirectory in cui salvare il file
     * @param dimensione Dimensione del file finale
     * @param in Stream di input
     */
    public Decripter(String name, String dir, ObjectInputStream tempIn, long tempDimensione) {
        directory = dir;
        fileName = name; in = tempIn;
        dimensione = tempDimensione;
        oFile = new File(directory, fileName);

        deReceiver();
    }
    /**
     * Metodo per la ricezione e riassemblamento del file
     */
    private void deReceiver() {
        int check = 0;
        //Ricerca ed eliminazione di un eventuale duplicato del file completo
        removeDuplicate();
        try {
            //Stream che accoderà i byte ricevuti
            fos = new FileOutputStream(oFile, true);
            //Blocco in cui vengono ricevuti i byte
            while (dimensione > check) {
                //Dimensione dei bytes in ricezione
                int tempDim = (int) in .readObject();
                //Preparo il buffer di byte
                byte[] mybytearray = new byte[tempDim];
                //Ricevo i byte
                in .readFully(mybytearray);
                //Traccio i byte che ho letto
                check += tempDim;
                //Scrivo su file
                fos.write(mybytearray);


                //Svuoto lo stream
                fos.flush();
                //Resetto il buffer
                mybytearray = null;
            }
            //Chiudo lo stream
            fos.close();
            fos = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Metodo per la rimozione del file completo già presente nella directory
     */
    public static void removeDuplicate() {
        File direc = new File(directory);
        for (File temp: direc.listFiles()) {
            if (temp.getName().equals(fileName))
                temp.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for any errors of the post.

Comment: Does it work OK on a smaller file?

Comment: Can you not tokenize the class and do it in chunks?

Comment: works correctly with file sizes between 100 MB and 1GB @DaveRlz

Comment: @ChrisCooney sorry, I did not understand the question xD

Comment: Slice up the file into smaller chunks and do the same operation with them.

Comment: I need this class (cripter) because it is called if the size of the file to send \ receive is greater than the heap memory of the Java VM

Answer (score 0):

If I've read your code correctly, the problem is that your sender format doesn't match your receiver format.

When you send you do this:

1. send file-name
2. send file-size
3. send chunk-size
4. send chunk-size bytes
5. go to 3

When you receive you do this:

1. send chunk-size
2. send chunk-size bytes
3. go to 1

If this isn't the problem, please provide an SSCCE ... so that we can examine the code that you are actually running.

Comment: Sorry for the SSCCE, I have read about that just now, however, the problem is not that because that part is not used by Decripter. Anyway give you an SSCCE as soon as possible since these two classes are part of a project Client Server ...

Comment: I found the error. The variable check was an integer, so when the size exceeded 2,147,483,647 (maximum number representable in int), the variable check became negative. Thanks anyway to everyone.